# Size relationship between body background image and absolute + relative containers CSS3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hopefully the title explains it pretty good (took some thinking i assure you), anyway i have a bg image attached to body by css:

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
background: url("../images/header_lg.jpg") no-repeat;
-moz-background-size: 100% auto;
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
-o-background-size: 100% auto;
background-size: 100% auto;
}
.fullwidth-head {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.fullwidth-head-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17%;
  left: 11%;
  width: 78%;
  height: 30%;
  background: #c5c5c5; /* just for visibility */
}
```

Two divs are applied ".fullwidth-head" which is the container and is relative and at the very top of the page by default as it is the first div, inside fullwidth-head is another absolute positioned div ".full-width-head-inner", now it works pretty good on desktop and does what i want it to do, but sure as i switch to portrait view it goes to pot due to really having no relation to the background image being resized, i did think of a small hack by adding an empty .png the same size as the body background image to keep the ratio and it would probably work, however im a bit reluctant to do this because of the extra load it would apply.

Html is below (not much thankfully) i have been at this for sometime and keep starting over until i get the required result that i am after:

```
<body>

<div class="fullwidth-head">
    <div class="fullwidth-head-inner">
    </div><!-- /.fullwidth-head-inner -->
</div><!-- /.fullwidth-head -->



<!-- js scripts in footer -->
```

So is there a way other than using a blank.png to fix the size of the relative container div where i can actually via css get the info i need to keep the same aspect ratio as the body bg image?

thanks

Comment: No sure I understood what you want, but I think you might simply be looking for the _padding-bottom hack_.

Comment: Thanks for replying, basically the css for .fullwidth-head is at 100% height, (thats cool for desktops), but that height stays 100% when going into portrait view due to screen proportion, the image gets resized down as expected, this moves the fullwidth-header-inner div too far down. I have two choices as i see it: a) media queries b) using a blank.png, ideally though if there is something in css3 or js that could pick up the size of the image as it resizes down for portrait view that would be a better option as the div would be exactly positioned no matter what, thanks

Comment: You need to know the image proportions resp. aspect ratio beforehand; but then the padding-bottom hack is an easy way to get an element to "resize" the same way as a real image would.

Comment: that works an absolute treat, ty for the heads up, i need to mark you as answered.. thnks again CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might simply be looking for what's known as the *padding-bottom hack*.

You need to know the image proportions resp. aspect ratio beforehand; but then it's an easy way to get an element to "resize" the same way as a real image would.

A few additional resources on that subject matter:

http://www.smashcompany.com/technology/the-bottom-padding-hack
http://andyshora.com/css-image-container-padding-hack.html
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/09/responsive-images-performance-problem-case-study/#the-padding-bottom-hack

Comment: thanks for that, the last link (smashingmagazine) is the one i referenced to apply the fix..